# При запуске прилож. в android studio компоненты на экране "съезжають"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Как решить трабл, чтобы при запуске все оставалось как ты делал в режиме дизайна. Параметр Infer Constaints выбран. Или это баг самой студии?

Comment: Как здесь [задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), чтобы получить полезный ответ

Comment: Попробуйте в дизайнере выбрать то же самое устройство по параметрам на котором вы запускаете, скорее всего у вас верстка едет из-за "неадаптивности", а вообще прикладывайте Layout, скриншоты и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Никак, это огромная проблема верстки от слова ЛЮБОЙ. Каждое устройство может иметь собственное разрешение экрана, размеры экрана и т.п. Особенно это заметно, если использовать пиксельную верстку. Есть два вариата, выхода из ситуации. 
1) Рисовать под каждый размер, разрешение экрана один и тот же layout
2)Более простой, но менее эффективный, использовать некое подобие процентной верстки.(Для `LinearLayout`). Так же пользоваться функционалом `RelativeLayout`(Выровнять по левому, правому краю, по центру, слева от объекта, справа от объекта, под объектом, над объектом и т.п.). Использовать `padding`и `layout_margin`. Ну а вообще, эта тема очень огромная и отразить ее в одном ответе просто не реально.